# Format **kwargs to f-string

Tags: python, keyword-argument, f-string

I am trying to format keyword arguments passed to a function, in such a way that the string output (has to be f-string in this case) would look like `arg1=arg1_value, arg2=arg2_value,...`

Apparently it is not possible to just do:

```
out = f'{**kwargs}'
```

so I have managed to do it in this way:

```py
def to_string(**kwargs):
    return ', '.join([f'{k}={v}' for k,v in kwargs.items()])

> to_string(a=1, b=2)
'a=1, b=2'
```

Is there a way to do this more simply?

Comment: use a lambda functuon??

Comment: `print(f'{kwargs}')`

Comment: @sadbro could you please provide an example?

Comment: @leaf_yakitori that returns a dict

Comment: Your sulotion seems prety good, the only thing I see that can be improved is that you can delete the brackets (`[]`) to turn the list comprehension to a generator expression. P.S. Another thing you might wanna look into is formating the value as a `repr` (by adding `!r`).

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack an iterable (cf [another question]) but not a dictionnary.
Because you want the exact same output as `f"{a=}, {b=}, {c=}"` you will not find a solution much shorter than what you already have.